# SVG fit containing element

Tags: html, css, svg

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/4/

I am trying to make it so the SVG expands and contracts to fill the blue area. For the life of me, I cannot understand why it doesn't appear, as I have set the svg properties to 100% width and height.

HTML

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
...
```

CSS

```
svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect to see here? And this might just be my own ignorance, but why is everything in the header and nothing in the body?

Comment: Currently the svg doesn't appear and doesnt fit the blue area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your SVG a viewbox set to 0 0 100 100 , make sur you draw your element within this area .

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
...
    <rect x="188" y="832"
```

and so on , you cannot expect to see anything there standing further than `x='100' y='100'`

To explain: if you reset viewbox to `0 0 1000 1000`  then **[the show goes on](http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/5/)**

Comment: Thank you, so to understand, the view box needs to be the outter dimensions of the svg elements, i.e the highest hight and the widest width?

Comment: @Jimmy yes , if you set viewbox to initial size of your SVG, it allows it to be rescaled automaticly to fit where it stands. you can clip your svg using viewbox attribue:http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/6/

Comment: A viewBox sets the coordinate system for the SVG contents. So anything inside i.e. `<rect>` elements and the like must be within that to be seen.

Comment: @RobertLongson it can be used to clip a part of an svg as well :) it is what he unfortunately did on the first place